# How to split a large file?

Tags: command-line, bash, regex

How can I pass all files in a list.txt which looks like

```
file1_1.txt
file1_2.txt
file1_3.txt
file1_4.txt
```

to the `split` command (there are other txt files in the dir) and make it return the parts numbered as in (assume file1_1.txt would be chunked into 4 parts)

```
file1_1_1.txt;
file1_1_2.txt;
file1_1_3.txt;
file1_1_4.txt
```

and so on....

Comment: line-wise version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/easy-way-to-split-a-large-text-file , binary version: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/break-a-large-file-into-smaller-pieces

Answer (score 7):

In order to be sure no line break you can use other option than `c`.

```
split -n #number
```

split a file by #number chunks so you can thus be sure they are equal and more no break in lines.Example

```
split -n 4 file.txt
```

This will split the file.txt into 4 chunks.

OR you can split by number of lines

```
split -l #number-of-lines
```

example

```
split -l 200 file.txt
```

This will split the file.txt into files each is 200 lines. But this is not accurate that all are of same length since the last file maybe less than that number chosen.

Now with respect to the naming. The default of the command split is to use a default suffix "x" and default prefixes "aa" "ab" "ac" ...

So in order to change those default you have to state a suffix to use.

in your case you can use

```
split -n #number file1_1.txt file1_1.
```

The output would be like `file1_1.aa file1_1.ab  file1_1.ac`

Else you can change the default prefix to be numberic using `-d`

```
  split -n #number -d file1_1.txt file1_1.
```

The output would be like `file1_1.00 file1_1.01  file1_1.02`

So you can't get the naming you want with default split unless you use some `awk` or `sed` with REGEX.

Now to read the set of files from a file lets called `files.list`

```
while IFS= read -r file

do split -n #number -d "$file" "$file"

done < files.list
```

**UPDATE:** I came to this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32626/split-a-file-by-line-and-have-control-over-resulting-files-extension

According to second answer

> recent versions (≥ 8.16) of gnu split one can use the
>   --additional-suffix switch to have control over the resulting extension. From man split:
>
> --additional-suffix=SUFFIX
>                 append an additional SUFFIX to file names. so when using that option:
>
> split -dl 10000 --additional-suffix=.txt words wrd the resulting
>   pieces will automatically end in .txt:
>
> wrd00.txt wrd01.txt

So in your case if your split version is >8.16 then you can do your need like this

```
split -n #number -d --additional-suffix=.txt file1_1.txt file1_1-
```

So output would be like

```
file1_1-00.txt file1_1-01.txt file1_1-02.txt .....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while read file; do split <some options> "$file"; done < list.txt
```

If your file names can contain whitespace or backslashes, use this instead:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do split <some options> "$file"; done < list.txt
```

Comment: which options are in split allowed...as i am passing the filenames from the list.txt I assume I just set the -n or -c argument there would that be correct? and the output would then be like file_1_1.aa and so on?

Comment: @Cyrus the OP requests much more than your answer Please update to satisfy the OP needs

Answer (score 1):

Here's my crude oneliner:

> awk -F'.' '{$3=$1;print $1"."$2" "$3"_"}' list.txt |  xargs -n2 split
>   --numeric-suffixes=1 -n 4 --suffix-length=1 --additional-suffix=".txt"

**Explanation**:

The file contains entries:

```
file1_1.txt
file1_2.txt
file1_3.txt
file1_4.txt
```

We take those with awk, and using dot as delimiter, create two-column list

```
file1_1.txt file1_1_
file1_2.txt file1_2_
file1_3.txt file1_3_
file1_4.txt file1_4_
```

Next, xargs takes that output, two entries per execution (-n2), and runs split with numeric suffixes starting at 1, split into 4 files, and add ".txt" at the end. And here is the demo of that oneliner:

[image]

Comment: Like my answer ? please leave an  upvote. Solved your problem ? click grey checkmark to accept the answer =)